# getting names displaying from firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display the contents of a firebase database. I know that I am reading them correctly as I am able to print them as they are read in. The problem is when I call the method to display them on screen, they are "out of range".

I know this means the the methods are being called simultaneously therefore the array is empty. I have tried the "Sleep()" method and doesn't work.

```
 //arrays of names and descriptions
    var Names:[String] = []
    var Desctiptions: [String] = []
```

inital method

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()


        getRestauraunt()


        //create slides
        scrollView.delegate = self
        slides = createSlides()
        setupSlideScrollView(slides: slides)
}
  func getRestauraunt(){

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.collection("Test").getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let name = document.get("Name") as! String
                    let description = document.get("Description") as! String

                    //print("Names: ",name," Description: ",description)

                    self.Names.append(name)
                    self.Desctiptions.append(description)

                }
            }
        }


    }
```

create slides method

```
 func createSlides() -> [Slide] {
        //firebase link
        let slide1:Slide = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Slide", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! Slide
        slide1.labelTitle.text = Names[0]
       }
```

I would like if someone could show me how to get the 'createSlides()' method to wait until the 'getRestauraunts()' method has finished. Thank you

Comment: Reserve capitalized properties for types, take advantage of `guard` or `if-else` to safely unwrap the snapshot before accessing it, and be more consistent with your coding (ex: if you reserve `viewDidLoad` for calling instance methods, don't just do it with some, do it with all). Start the good habits early!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call it from the end of the `getrestaurant()`'s  `getDocuments` closure

```
 func getRestauraunt(){

  //as before...

            } else {
                for document in snapshot!.documents {
                    let name = document.get("Name") as! String
                    let description = document.get("Description") as! String
                    self.Names.append(name)
                    self.Desctiptions.append(description)
                }
                self.createSlides()
            }
        }
    }
```

As an aside, it might also be worth creating a simple `Document` struct with name and description properties, and just having the one array: `[Document]`

Comment: so simple, Thank you!